# Fastest way to responsively modify svg arcs?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using SVG to create a number of rectangles which extensively use arcs. The problem comes when trying to make the SVG responsive, as the arc coordinates will remain the same when the SVG is inside a viewBox and not scale well.

At the moment, I have come up with a 'proof of concept'. When the parent container is resized, the SVG paths will be removed then redrawn. I am just testing with the height attribute at the moment, which I have set as a `vw` unit.

http://plnkr.co/edit/duFwRXxVw5HREgFDQS0a?p=preview

As you can see it works, but the idea of removing and redrawing the SVG paths on resize seems like it could be very slow, especially if there is a lot more of them. I think it would be much more effective to modify the existing paths, rather than constantly removing and redrawing them on scratch. I am wondering if it would be possible to attach event listeners to each of the arcs coordinates and just change those figures when the container is resized?

I am also open to suggestions to other methods that could make this quicker, if redrawing the SVG is the only viable option, then maybe it would make more sense to recreate this implementation in a `<canvas>`? I would like to attach mouse hover events to each of the paths eventually, so I'm not sure if using canvas would be an advantage in that regard?

Hope the problem is clear, please let me know if you need me to explain further!

Code Below;

---

```js
var doc = document;
var times = ['times', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

function getNode(n, v) {
    n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
    for (var p in v)
        n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function (m, p, o, s) {
            return "-" + m.toLowerCase();
        }), v[p]);
    return n
}

// CREATE TIME LIST

function createList() {


    for (var i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        var el = doc.getElementById('times');
        el.appendChild(doc.createElement('div'))
        el.getElementsByTagName('div')[i].setAttribute('class', 'info')
        doc.getElementsByClassName('info')[i].innerHTML = times[i]
    }


}

// CREATE SVG

function createSvg() {

    times.shift()
    
    var container = doc.getElementById('headings')
    var svg = doc.getElementById('graphic')

    var height = 100;
    var width = 100;

    var cellHeight = height / times.length;
    var cellWidth = width;
    
    var cHeight = container.clientHeight;
    var rHeight = cHeight / 100;

    var perc = (n) => (height / 16) * n;

    var container = doc.getElementById('headings')

    var calcY = '6.25'

    var y;


    if(height < cHeight){
        y = (calcY / rHeight).toString()

        var fixHeight = (calcY - y) * 2;

        perc = (n) => (((height / 16) * n) + fixHeight)
    } else {
        y = calcY
        perc = (n) => (((height / 16) * n))
    }
    var rectA = getNode('path', {
        d: 'm0 ' + y +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 6.25 -' + y +
        'h87.5' +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 6.25 ' + y +
        'v' + perc(4.5).toString() +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 -6.25 ' + y +
        'h-43.75 ' +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 0 -6.25 ' + y +
        'v' + perc(1).toString() +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 -6.25 ' + y +
        'h-31.25 ' +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 -6.25 -' + y,
        fill: 'steelblue'
    })


    var rectB = getNode('path', {
        d: 'm0 ' + (height - y).toString() +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 0 6.25 ' + y +
        'h87.5 ' +
        'a6.25 -' + y + ' 0 0 0 6.25 -' + y +
        'v-' + perc(7.5).toString() +
        'a-6.25 -' + y + ' 0 0 0 -6.25 -' + y +
        'h-43.75 ' +
        'a-6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 0 -6.25 ' + y +
        'v'+ perc(1).toString()  +
        'a-6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 1 -6.25 ' + y +
        'h-31.25 ' +
        'a6.25 ' + y + ' 0 0 0 -6.25 ' + y,
        fill: 'crimson'
    })

    var rects = [rectA, rectB]

    for (let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
        svg.append(rects[i])
    }

}

// REMOVE ON RESIZE

function resize() {
    var svg = doc.getElementById('graphic')

    var ele = svg.getElementsByTagName('path')

    for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){
        ele[i].remove()
    }

    createSvg()
}

createList();
createSvg();
```

```css
#headings {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40vw;
  margin: 15px 15px;
}

#headings #times {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#headings #times .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.7vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#headings #svg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#headings #svg .heading {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headings">
    <div id="times"></div>
    <div id="svg">
      <div class="heading">Rects</div>
      <svg id="graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" onresize="resize()"></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Side Note: If you are interested to see how the arcs would look without the responsive scaling but increased parent height, [click here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/M7KVnFUuB8pXb6gBykcn?p=preview)

Comment: "the idea of removing and redrawing the SVG on resize seems like it could be very slow" Could be? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Jordan In the plunk and code on display in the question there is an implementation that removes and redraws the SVG paths on resize. Even with just one element it seems slow to me, and I've heard (unless I'm mistaken) constantly removing and drawing things onto the DOM should be avoided. Although I'm happy to accept I'm wrong if that's the case

Comment: I'm not an SVG expert so I'll take your word for it. How about having a single resize event listener that keeps a reference to each `<path>` element and updates their `d` attributes?

Comment: Why not expand your example so it has lots of rectangles (representing your app). Then you will know whether its going to be slow and possibly avoid early optimisation. If it is slow, I have found that replacing the `path` (or `d`) inside the `svg` was fast. And it was better to have one complex path then many littles ones, because it seemed that the rendering was then hardware optimised - and rendering, not JavaScript was the bottleneck.

Comment: Chrome developer tools / Timeline is a really good tool to see where the time is going.

Comment: @Jordan Yeah that sounds like it might work, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @James Yeah that's a good idea, I'll work on expanding the example tomorrow. Would it still be possible to have each rectangle as a different colour if they were all inside the same path? Thanks for the tip with the Chrome Timeline, I've never gone into chrome tools past looking at the console, so will explore soon

Answer (score 1):

you can get by, by using percentages and masks to resemble your drawing. This way it will be "responsive" and scale to any size you want, without changing your path at all...
Stroking would be possible,but will be very tricky ;-)

```js
function changeSize() {
  var w = Math.random() * 200 + 100
  var h = Math.random() * 200 + 100
  svg.setAttribute("width", w)
  svg.setAttribute("height", h)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSize()">change size</button><br/>
<svg id="svg" width="50" height="200">
  <symbol id="arc" overflow="visible">
    <path d="M0,0H10A10 10 0 0 0 0 10z" stroke="white" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="arc2" overflow="visible">
    <path d="M0,0H10A10 10 0 0 0 0 10z" transform="rotate(180)" stroke="white" />
  </symbol>
  <mask id="upper">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="40%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="white" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="60%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="white" />
    <use xlink:href="#arc" x="50%" y="40%" fill="white" />
  </mask>

  <mask id="lower">
    <rect x="0" y="60%" width="100%" height="40%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="white" />
    <rect x="50%" y="40%" width="50%" height="60%" rx="10" ry="10" fill="white" />
    <use xlink:href="#arc2" x="50%" y="60%" fill="white" />
  </mask>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue" mask="url(#upper)" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" mask="url(#lower)" />
</svg>
```